# NestJS + Kafka + app.connectMicroservice() + ClientsModule.registerAsync() double initialization parameters (clientId)

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, microservices

I have NestJS + Kafka consumer/producer. I initialize Kafka twice, first in the main.ts via `app.connectMicroservice()` / `NestFactory.createMicroservice()`, second in a module via `ClientsModule.register()` / `ClientsModule.registerAsync()`.

Full sources are below.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does it look the way it should look (i.e. 2 different locations to initialize the same thing)
2. Should I use the same options (such as `clientId`) for both cases or the client IDs should be different?

**Clarification**: everything works when I put it the way it is below, but once I remove the microservice, the consumer does not join the channel (no messages are consumed), and (obviously) once I remove it from module, I can not use it in a module.

**main.ts:**

```
    const microserviceKafka = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          clientId: 'someClientId',
          brokers: [
            configService.get('KAFKA_HOST') +
              ':' +
              configService.get('KAFKA_PORT'),
          ],
        },
        consumer: {
          groupId: 'someGroupId',
        },
      },
    });
```

**whatever.module.ts**:

```
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: 'WhateverModule',
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          name: 'WhateverModule',
          transport: Transport.KAFKA,
          options: {
            client: {
              clientId: 'someClientId',
              brokers: [
                configService.get('KAFKA_HOST') +
                  ':' +
                  configService.get('KAFKA_PORT'),
              ],
            },
            consumer: {
              groupId: 'someGroupId',
            },
          },
        }),
      },
    ]),
```